# Android SQLite Insert-Select

Tags: android, sqlite, select-insert

There are two different methods for inserting a row into table:

- **execSql**, using it I can execute sql statements with SELECT - INSERT. But *it doesn't return id of new row.*
- different **inserts** - I can get insert-id here, but I can't create insert queries with substitution values from another table.

I can split my query into two, but isn't it slower, than one query?

Comment: If you need to substitute values in one table by values from another I would consider creating TRIGGERS in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your insert however you like, then execSql `"select last_insert_rowid()"`.

Comment: Thanks. I've forgot about that sql function.